# Invalid aliases in linux shell

Tags: linux, shell

I'd like to run some script.

It need alias to modify command.

but it seem invalid.

ex:

```
root@161310ea476b:/tmp# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
ls /tmp
root@161310ea476b:/tmp#
root@161310ea476b:/tmp# ./test.sh
test.sh
root@161310ea476b:/tmp# . test.sh
test.sh
```

now I used alias

```
root@161310ea476b:/tmp# shopt -s expand_aliases
root@161310ea476b:/tmp# alias ls="ls -al"
```

it works.

```
 root@161310ea476b:/tmp# . test.sh
 total 12
 drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 Jun 21 09:41 .
 drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Jun 21 09:39 ..
 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   22 Jun 21 09:41 test.sh
```

but this case wasn't works. alias seem invalid.

```
 root@161310ea476b:/tmp# ./test.sh
 test.sh
 root@161310ea476b:/tmp#
```

How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are not inherited by the subshell used to execute your script.

Please see the answer provided here:
[Aliases in subshell](https://superuser.com/a/319548)

Alternatively, you could create your alias as a function (instead of an alias), export it, and THEN run your script.

Create a function...

```
function ls() {
    /bin/ls -al
}
```

...export it...

```
export -f ls
```

...and run your script

```
. ./test.sh
```

Of course, don't forget you've created a function `ls`. (Note: it should only exist as long as the shell you exported it from --- and any subshells from it --- is/are open).

Comment: @John :: If you feel this answer solved your problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This way, other people with the same question will know it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. this issue is solved. your method is valid for me.